# Launch URL without truncating key/value pairs

Tags: ruby

Does anyone know how I can get a full url with multiple key value pairs to open in a browser? I'm automating opening a bunch of urls and they are all truncated upon launching after the first key/value pair.  See below:

I'm running:

`system("open https://someradurl.awesaome.com/approvals?code=guid&context=anotherguid")`

but what opens in the browser is:

`https://someradurl.awesaome.com/approvals?code=guid`

As you can see it strips off the context and any other additional keys upon launching.

I know I could use the launchy gem to achieve this, and that works, but I'm looking for a native to Ruby solution. I'd also like to understand why system("open ") doesn't work.

Help would be greatly appreciated.  I've been noodling on this for about a week.

I'm running a Mac: ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16] if that's helpful.

Answer (score 5):

You want to wrap your URL within your command in double quotes, otherwise as you've seen, anything after & is stripped out as & is an operator character in most shells. As the command is a string in double quotes already, you can use double quotes within the command using an escaped double quote, `\"`, i.e. `"\"a string within a string\""`.

Try:

```
system("open \"https://someradurl.awesaome.com/approvals?code=guid&context=anotherguid\"")
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wrapping the URL in single quotes is even better because they guarantee the shell doesn't try to interpret anything between them.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR - links should be enclosed in single quotes

`system("xdg-open 'https://someradurl.awesaome.com/approvals?code=guid&context=anotherguid'")`

---

Instead of `open` use `xdg-open`

From the `man page` of xdg-open

```
EXAMPLES
           xdg-open 'http://www.freedesktop.org/'

       Opens the freedesktop.org website in the user's default browser.

           xdg-open /tmp/foobar.png

       Opens the PNG image file /tmp/foobar.png in the user's default image viewing
       application.
```

And this is not a ruby specific issue.

Comment: `xdg-open` is usually available on Linux only. On macOS, the usable command is indeed called `open`.